# Routing setup for a user account page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I see this quite a bit with online apps. Lets take, for example, the following url:

```
https://github.com/account
```

For something like above, the route (in Rails 3) would look like:

```
get '/account', :to => 'users#edit', :as => 'account'
```

Or is there a better way to do this? Perhaps create its own Accounts controller? How would you go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably instead of

```
get '/account', :to => 'users#edit', :as => 'account'
```

it would be

```
et '/account', :to => 'users#show', :as => 'account'
```

With an edit button if the displayed user is the logged in one (like how github does it)

But yeah to me that seems like the easiest way to accomplish such a task